# mongoDB: Conversion $dateFromString shows date as string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have created a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uKKpeRJY57r)

As you will see in final output "dateHour" field shows as string. 
I am converting it to be date object using `$dateFromString` object. but it still comes out as string.

Expected - It should be in Date format like : `"dateHour": "2020-03-19T18:15:00.000Z"`,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `$toString` operator which converts from `ISODate` to `string`:

```
dateHour: {
    $let: {
        vars: {
        parsedDate: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$_id.dateHour",
                    format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H"
                }   
            }
        },
        in: {
            $add: [
                "$$parsedDate",
                {
                    $multiply: [ "$_id.minuteBucket",  900000 ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UpF6gYwLnNL)

Comment: hope to get some more help on this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163597/mongodb-show-minutebucket-in-time-value-as-ending-time-for-the-interval