# mongoDB: Show MinuteBucket in Time value as ending time for the interval

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have created [Mongo PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vZXyBiBNLnn)

Currently dateHour field is dividing time by 15min interval.

For example - 
if

```
`"updatedAt": ISODate("2020-03-20T18:16:50.000Z")`
```

it shows as :

```
 "dateHour": ISODate("2020-03-20T18:15:00Z"),
```

so First 15min bucket is represented as **18:00:000z** (this covers minutes from 1 to 15)

second 15min bucket is represented as **18:15:000z** (this covers minutes from 15 to 30)
and so on....

Expected -

First 15min bucket should be displayed as ***18:15:000z*** (this covers minutes from 1 to 15)
second 15min bucket should be displayed as ***18:30:000z*** (this covers minutes from 15 to 30)
and so on....

Basically it should show ending time for that interval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [$trunc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trunc/) which is this case converts the result of `$divide` into lower minuteBucket, you can use [$ceil](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ceil/index.html) instead:

```
minuteBucket: {
    $ceil: {
        $divide: [ { $minute: "$updatedAt"  },  15.0  ]
    }
},
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6jZlHzjuQAm)

Comment: could you pls help make this query compatible for version 3.6? $dateFromString does not take format field... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165765/mongodb-how-to-parse-date-in-3-6-mongodb-version